# How to selectively apply processing algorithm to certain color channel(s) in Java

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I'm developing an image processing library for Android which has ability to apply adjustments to image.

At first, I process each bits like this:

```
public int[] getProcessedPixels(int[] pixels) {
    int a, r, g, b;
    for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {

        a = Color.alpha(pixels[i]);
        r = Color.red(pixels[i]);
        g = Color.green(pixels[i]);
        b = Color.blue(pixels[i]);

        a = doSomethingWithThisChannel(a);
        r = doSomethingWithThisChannel(r);
        g = doSomethingWithThisChannel(g);
        b = doSomethingWithThisChannel(b);

        // Merge back all 4 channels to pixel value
        pixels[i] = Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
    }

    return pixels;
}

// Usage sample
int[] pixels = bitmap.getAllPixels(); // each pixels is hexa 0xAARRGGBB
int[] resultPixels = getProcessedPixels(pixels); // it returns  result pixels
```

Since I'm developing **a library**, I want to let developers who use it to be able to **apply "doSomethingWithThisChannel" method to any channel(s) as needed**

I want to change the method like this (it's a copy of the above method, but simplified):

```
public int[] getProcessedPixels(int[] pixels) {
    // assume process all channels if not specified
    return getProcessedPixels(pixels, Channel.ALL);
}

public int[] getProcessedPixels(int[] pixels, int channels) {
    int a, r, g, b;
    for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i] = doSomethingWithTHESEChannels(pixels[i], channels);
    }

    return pixels;
}

// Usage sample
int channels = Channel.RED | Channel.GREEN; // ONLY apply processing to RED & GREEN channels
int[] pixels = bitmap.getAllPixels(); // each pixels is hexa 0xAARRGGBB
int[] resultPixels = getProcessedPixels(pixels, channels);
```

This is my static class to define "bitmasks" (cmiiw) for each ARGB color channel I used in the code above:

```
public class Channel {
    public static final int NONE = 0x00000000;
    public static final int ALL = 0xffffffff;
    public static final int ALPHA = 0xff000000;
    public static final int RED = 0x00ff0000;
    public static final int GREEN = 0x0000ff00;
    public static final int BLUE = 0x000000ff;
}
```

Do you have any suggestion how should I implement `doSomethingWithTHESEChannels` method above? I'm pretty sure it will involve bitmask/bit-manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a implementation of the *doSomethingWithTHESEChannels* method as per your design :

```
    private int doSomethingWithTHESEChannels(int i, int channels) {

    if (Channel.NONE == channels) {
        return i;
    }

    int a, r, g, b;
    a = (i & Channel.ALPHA) >> 24;
    r = (i & Channel.RED) >> 16;
    g = (i & Channel.GREEN) >> 8;
    b = i & Channel.BLUE;

    int cur = channels & Channel.ALL;
    if (cur == Channel.ALL) {
        System.out.println("all found");
        a = transform(a);
        r = transform(r);
        g = transform(g);
        b = transform(b);

    } else {
        cur = channels & Channel.ALPHA;
        if (cur == Channel.ALPHA) {
            System.out.println("alpha found");
            a = transform(a);
        }
        cur = channels & Channel.RED;
        if (cur == Channel.RED) {
            System.out.println("red found");
            r = transform(r);
        }
        cur = channels & Channel.GREEN;
        if (cur == Channel.GREEN) {
            System.out.println("green found");
            g = transform(g);
        }

        cur = channels & Channel.BLUE;
        if (cur == Channel.BLUE) {
            System.out.println("blue found");
            b = transform(b);
        }

    }

    return (a << 24 | r << 16 | g << 8 | b);

}
```

The transform method is the operation to be applied to a channel. The *Sysouts* are just for testing purposes. You may change the type of a,r,g,b variables to byte with proper type-castings if needed.

However, I suggest you to move the above channel detection blocks(if conditions) to the *getProcessedPixels* method itself. Then you can pass the entire *pixels* array to a transform method. This way you will eliminate the redundant condition checks for each pixel. If you need hint on this, just leave a reply, I will update the answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Your code seems right and makes sense, I'll try it.

Comment: I think you're right about moving if blocks to the processing method, it might gives me some performance boost. Great suggestion!

Comment: my pleasure! Your lib'll be free? I would like to use.

Comment: The code is still changing a lot while I'm using it for my work. I'll publish it on github when ready. The goal is an open instagram-like filter library by mimicking photoshop's action & blending modes :)